# How to convert asynchronous call to synchronous for firebase access Amazon web service Lambda function in java

Tags: java

I want to call a AWS lambda function within which I am connecting to a Firebase database. The problem is that the handler executes before I get the needed data from Firebase.

Comment: *"How to convert asynchronous call to synchronous"* In the general case, you simply can't.

Answer (score 0):

A recipe to convert an asynchronous call into a synchronous one:

Let's assume the async call is called `fooAsync()`, and that you have some way to check a result condition when the operation is completed. You can introduce your own `volatile boolean fooComplete` to track this.

Then:

```
public void fooSyncWrapper() {
    volatile boolean fooComplete = false;

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fooAsync();

            while (!fooComplete) {
                // busy wait on completion condition
                fooComplete = checkIfComplete();
            }

            // task is completed, thread will join
        }
    };

    thread.start();
    thread.join();
}
```