# How can I convert a method to asynchronous of my web service?

Tags: java, web, soap, soap-client

I currently have a web soap service method that works fine, but I would like to know how I can convert it to return a confirmation that the message has been received and that the client does not wait until I finish the process.

```
@Service
@WebService(serviceName = 
  "getStudents",wsdlLocation="/wsdl/Students.wsdl")
  public class StudentsImpl implements Students {


   public StudentResponse getStudents(StudentRequest 
   request) {

       **********************
   }
 }


public class StudentResponse
  {
    private String status;
    private Date timeStamp;
    ....................
  }
```

I would like to know how I can respond with an "OK" status and also the time.

```
    @WebService
    public abstract interface Students
    {

       @WebResult(name="response")
       @XmlElement(required=true, name="request")
       public abstract StudentResponse 
       getStudents(@WebParam(name="request") StudentRequest 
       request);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm interestingly enough this seems to the be *inverse* of the last question I answered, [Howto Convert an async call to blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698913/how-to-convert-asynchronous-call-to-synchronous-for-firebase-access-amazon-web-s/43699028#43699028).

So the steps are:

- Execute the blocking call in a new thread.
- Introduce a listener interface
- Invoke the listener from the thread when the blocking call completed
- Introduce a new async wrapper which can be invoked from the caller.

Assuming your blocking call is `fooBlocking()`, do:

```
public class MyKoolClass {
    // .. kool functionalities here ...

    public interface Listener {
        void onTaskCompleted(String message);
    }

    public void fooAsyncWrapper() {
        new FooTask(new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(final String message) {
                System.out.println("So complete, bruh" + message);
            }    
        }).start();
    }

    public static class FooTask extends Thread {
        Listener listener;

        public FooTask(final Listener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            fooBlocking();
            listener.onTaskCompleted("Sup baws.");
        }
    }
```